# How do I get my network card's model number without opening my computer box?

Tags: windows, networking

How do I get my network card's model number without opening my computer box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in Windows, open device manager and expand Network Adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Linux:
use the commands lspci,  lspci -v, lshw, lshw -a

---

Windows:

More detailed informations than the device manager can be provided by some as colled "hardware info" programs.

Une i linke in particular is "Pc Wizard"
http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html

Is made from the same producers of the famous Cpu-z(cpu info program)